# Redirect output of a file to the write command

Tags: bash, unix, redirectstandardoutput

I am trying to redirect the standard outupt of a file to the `write` command and display the contents of the file (with color changes) in the terminal of the other user.

The contents of the file whose output is to be displayed is (filename is menu_sys.sh)

`echo -e "\t\t\033[4;41m Welcome to Internal Messaging System \033[0;0m"`

When i use the code `$ sh menu_sys.sh |  write 680613`  the output is `^[[4;41m Welcome to Internal Messaging System^[[0;0m`

Tried using the standard output redirection using `&1>` but that too did not work

But i need the output to be in the formatted condition.

Comment: The terminology 'standard output of a file' is odd; commands or programs have standard outputs — files are often where you send the standard output of a command, but files don't have a standard output of their own.  Your script, `menu_sys.sh`, generates output, and that is sent to `write 680613`.  The standard `write` command will try to send that message to the terminal of user `680613`.  Is that you?  What are you expecting the escape sequences to do?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no the terminal user `680613` is someone else. By the term standard output of the file i meant the output of the code contained in the file menu_sys.sh I need the output to be displayed to another user at a different terminal. Using the escape sequencse i am trying to change the color of the text and the background color in which the text `Welcome to internal Messaging System` is displayed

Answer (score 0):

If the write command allowed arbitrary control characters to be sent to the terminal of another user, that would be a flagrant security problem. In fact, it sanitizes the contents of the message to be sent so as to render control characters harmless. That's why you see the ESC control character as the two ASCII characters '^' and '[' on the other user's terminal.

As an aside: As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) mentioned, "standard output of a file" doesn't make any sense. Actually what you appear to be doing is sending the standard output of a command (`echo`) to the `write` command, not the "standard output of a file". Or if you meant to send the *contents* of a file to the other user (using a command like `write 680613 < somefile`) that would be OK too.

Comment: Then how do i send in some formatted text (as in a text with different font color) to the terminal of another user. I need to make a system that can be used to send notices to the other users of the terminal from the admin

Comment: You don't. One problem in particular is that you have no way of finding out what terminal type (`$TERM` environment variable) the other user is using, so you wouldn't know which esacpe sequences to send even if the system let you send them.

Comment: So is there any other way to achieve the objective

Comment: Each machine is using Xterm

Comment: Well then you can write your own custom environment-specific version of the `write` command. Make sure you filter escape sequences aggressively, lest you introduce exactly the kind of security hole `write` tries to prevent! No generic solution can make such assumptions as that every user is using a single terminal type known in advance.